# add_index Ruby on Rails Joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a couple of models like so:

```
User has_many :orders
Order belongs_to :user
```

I've been reading that an index can speed up larger queries and it all makes sense, but I don't understand how I should setup an index on a `joins` or `includes`.

So if I have the query `Order.joins(:user).where(order_status: "Cancelled")` how would I use `add_index` to optimize this query? I assume the same logic would apply to `Order.includes(:user).where(order_status: "Cancelled")`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add table references to migrations, rails will be automatically add index for the foreign key. Here in this case, `user_id` would have been indexed if you look at `schema.rb` file.

Now to make the query faster, you will have to add index for `order_status` in the orders table.

```
rails g migration AddOrderStatusIndexToOrders

def change
  add_index :orders, :order_status
end
```

If you want to remove the index later, can be done like

```
def change
  remove_index :orders, :order_status
end
```

Comment: This makes me think the other answer is just redundant, right?

Comment: The other one results in an error (`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR`) since users table don't have any reference to order.

Answer (score 0):

You add your index in a migration:

```
def change
  add_index :users, :orders
end
```

And that's it, Rails will handle the rest

Comment: Can you please explain what this does? Like what fields are being indexed? I know the primary key is already indexed but does this just index the foreign key `user_id` in the orders table?

Comment: http://www.rakeroutes.com/blog/increase-rails-performance-with-database-indexes/ check out this, it has a pretty good explanation of indexing

Comment: I've seen this article before, I'm just curious exactly what happens when you specify two table names rather than a table name + attribute name. All he discusses here is the latter.

Comment: This will results error. Have you tried this in your local before posting this ?